# Ruby class_eval and yield

Tags: ruby

Man, I'm peeling the layers of the onion today, anyway here's the code

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(dynamic_methods)
    @arr = Array.new(dynamic_methods)
    @arr.each { |m|
      self.class.class_eval do
        define_method(m) do
          "<#{yield self if block_given?}>" 
        end
      end
    }
    end
end

tmp = MyClass.new ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']
tmp.method1 do |t|
  "here"
end
```

My problem is that I'm trying to access "here" within define_method(m) when the method is being executed, not when created. The current statement "<#{yield self if block_given?}>" doesn't give me that. And in case you are wondering, I have to keep this part of the code as is but I can make all the changes I want to MyClass.

```
tmp = MyClass.new ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']
tmp.method1 do |t|
  "here"
end
```

Can anyone help with the syntax? Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE: See below for my answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
define_method(m) do
  "<#{yield self if block_given?}>" 
end
```

with:

```
define_method(m) do |&block|
  "<#{block.call if block}>" 
end
```

This should work for 1.8.7 and up. You may also try to use `module_eval`:

```
self.class.module_eval %Q{
  def #{m}(&block)
    "<\#{block.call if block}>"
  end
}
```

Comment: Sadly you are right, I'm on 1.8.6 and it barfed (syntax error) on &block.

Comment: In that case you may surrender to `module_eval`, which takes a string: 

    module_eval %Q{def #{m}(&block) 
                      "<#{block.call if block}>"
                   end}

Comment: Sorry that also caused an error, this time it's "undefined local variable or method `block'"

Comment: Correct, you'd need to escape the inner '#', so that it does not get evaluated straight away. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: This is maddening, now it has this error "warning: multiple values for a block parameter (0 for 1)". Also thanks for the several times you've tried to help me so far.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to reproduce the warning, as I don't have 1.8.6. It must be rather buggy compared to 1.8.7, so, you may consider upgrading :)

Comment: Good idea except I'm concerned about 1.8.7 breaking my existing code, thanks for your gallant effort though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of feedback from Sergei and some tinkering on my own, I manage to get it working

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(dynamic_methods)
    @arr = Array.new(dynamic_methods)
    @arr.each { |m|
      self.class.module_eval %Q{
        def #{m}(&block)
          yield(self) if block_given?
        end
      end
    }
    end
end

tmp = MyClass.new ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']
tmp.method1 do |t|
  "here"
end
```

As you can tell, there are some minor tweaks to Sergei's suggestions, so thanks for all your help Sergei.